# Compare partition based on minimum pairwise distance

Tags: discrete-optimization, set-partition

Suppose I have a set of objects $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \} $ with some metric space defined $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_+$. And i have is the gram matrix $G$ instead,  $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $G_{ij} = d(x_i, x_j)$.

For any subset of $S \subseteq X$, I care about this quantity

$$
f(S) := \textbf{min} \sum_{i \in S} d(i, \alpha), \forall \alpha \in S
$$

And my problem is how to select an optimal partition $(L, R) $ of $X$ from some set of partitions $P$ efficient, such that $f(L) + f(R)$ is minimized ?

$$
L^*, R^* = \textbf{argmin}_{(L, R) \in P} f(L) + f(R)
$$

And $P$ has more than 1 element, so it's not a trivial problem.

Comment: In the definition of $f(S)$, do you mean $\min_{\alpha\in S}$?  And is $P$ a given finite set of partitions?  That is, we are not allowed to select an arbitrary $L$ and $R=X\setminus L$.

Comment: the definition of $f(S)$ is for all possible $\alpha \in S$, the minimum sum of the distance from all other elements to it. and $P$ is a given finite set of partitions yes. It's not a powerset, so arbitrary $L$ might not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that would avoid some recomputation is to loop once through $P$, storing the values of $f(L)$ and $f(R)$, and updating the incumbent if $f(L)+f(R)$ is smaller.  Each time you need to compute some $f(S)$, first check whether you already know its value from a previous step ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).